# What is the best approach to compare two columns with data in a table?

Tags: c#

I want to compare data in datatable, columns by columns auto by under 1 rules.

[image]

In this picture, I will compare by pair columns `Ax_y` vs `Bx_y`.

```
A0_0 vs B0_0

A1_1 vs B1_1

...........
```

I tried will code:

```
foreach(DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
    if (r["A0_0"] == r["B0_0"])
    {
       // do something 
    }
}
```

But this fails, I want to loop all rows and compare. But I have about 50 columns, do this manual is not good idea.

Note: in this a picture I draw sample columns. In real database it will like:

`A0_0   B0_0   A0_1   B0_1   A1_0   B1_0   A1_1   B1_1    A2_0   B2_0   A2_1   B2_1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the columns, In each iteration of the Rows. Something like the following:

```
foreach (DataRow r in myTableData.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < myTableData.Columns.Count - 1; i+=2)
    {
        if (r[i] == r[i + 1])
        {
            // do something;
        }
    }

}
```

Here the Inner loop will Iterate through the columns for each row, And It will compare `ith` column data with `i+1th`. ie., when `i=1` it will compare `r["A0_0"] and r["B0_0"]`. We skipped `0th` column since its for the `ID`

Comment: I got it. You're awesome.